# Can i do rolling upgrade of Oracle 11g (NOT RAC) in a Veritas Cluster Sever setup?

Tags: database, oracle, upgrade, database-administration

We have 2 node Veritas Cluster Server setup running Oracle 11g with 1 active primary and the other passive secondary with auto failover setup. Wanted to upgrade from 11.2.0.3r6 to 11.2.0.4r1 , Is it possible to do an upgrade without application downtime like upgrading one node at a time ?

Although Oracle has documented http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10803/schedule_outage.htm#HABPT5313 but mostly they talk about their own cluster solution like RAC /Clusterware/ASM etc and not anything related to VCS or IBM HACMP or Solaris cluster with oracle setup.  Also oracle only certifies the patch for Rolling upgrade Compatible with RAC only ?

Also how does the application need to handle when 1 node goes offline for upgrade , does it need catch the connection error and re-connect for the existing connections and in-flight transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not. You have to at least bounce the DB an start it with new *patched* binaries.

Rolling upgrades on RAC(active-active cluster) also require instances to be restarted one-by-one. This can have no (minimal) impact on application when your application is TAF capable.

RAC cluster is "active-active" while VCS is active-pasive in most instalations. RAC cluster DB can "offer" a possibility to apps to close non-active DB connections and application will open new ones on some other DB node. Then you can freely upgrade the RAC node and restart it. Rolling upgrade in Oracle's terminology means that: "It supports to have 2 or more active cluster nodes and each of them runs different version of binaries". i.e. it is supports situation when one active cluster node already uses patched binaries while the others  (also active) are still on the older version.

PS: I also have to note that on Oracle 9i it was possible to have RAC cluster cooperating with VCS. But also in this case it was active-acrive cluster.

Comment: I saw this article making me feel it's possible, http://kmit4u.blogspot.com/2010/09/veritas-cluster-steps-before-upgrading.html , does it make sense to you ?

Comment: Well it makes sense, but even in this case you have donwtime. Failover -> db must shut be down and started on the other node. All db connections are lost. Also check installation notes for your patch (fixpack). Many of them do require dabase to start started in *exclusive* mode. `STARTUP UPGRADE` or `STARTUP MIGRATE`.